# Eigen PartialPivLU example won't compile

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to compile the Eigen3 [PartialPivLU example](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__InplaceDecomposition.html)

> MatrixXd A(2,2);
>   A << 2, -1, 1, 3;
>   PartialPivLU >> lu(A);

but I get compiler errors (see below).

If I remove the "Ref<> it compiles OK. Does anyone know how to use PartialPivLU with Ref<>?

Thanks
Steve

```
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/LU:23:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:2,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h: In instantiation of 'class Eigen::PartialPivLU<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >':
test3.cc:9:36:   required from here
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:52:10: error: 'Options' is not a member of 'Eigen::PartialPivLU<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > >::MatrixType {aka Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >}'
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h: In instantiation of 'Eigen::PartialPivLU<MatrixType>::PartialPivLU(const MatrixType&) [with _MatrixType = Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >; Eigen::PartialPivLU<MatrixType>::MatrixType = Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >]':
test3.cc:9:36:   required from here
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:213:26: error: no matching function for call to 'Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::Ref(Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 0>::Index, Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 0>::Index)'
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:213:26: note: candidates are:
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:308:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:211:12: note: template<class Derived> Eigen::Ref::Ref(const Eigen::DenseBase<OtherDerived>&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(bool)(typename Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<_PlainObjectType, _Options, _StrideType> >::match<Derived>::MatchAtCompileTime), Derived>::type*)
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:211:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/LU:23:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:2,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:213:26: note:   mismatched types 'const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>' and 'Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 0>::Index {aka long int}'
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:308:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:204:12: note: template<class Derived> Eigen::Ref::Ref(Eigen::PlainObjectBase<OtherDerived>&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(bool)(typename Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<_PlainObjectType, _Options, _StrideType> >::match<Derived>::MatchAtCompileTime), Derived>::type*)
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:204:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/LU:23:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:2,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:213:26: note:   mismatched types 'Eigen::PlainObjectBase<OtherDerived>' and 'Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 0>::Index {aka long int}'
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:308:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:194:12: note: template<class Derived> Eigen::Ref::Ref(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<OtherDerived>&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(bool)(typename Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Ref<_PlainObjectType, _Options, _StrideType> >::match<Derived>::MatchAtCompileTime), Derived>::type*)
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:194:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/LU:23:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:2,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/PartialPivLU.h:213:26: note:   mismatched types 'const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<OtherDerived>' and 'Eigen::MapBase<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, 0>::Index {aka long int}'
In file included from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:308:0,
                 from /apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from test3.cc:2:
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:188:76: note: Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::Ref(const Eigen::Ref<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >&)
/apps/eigen/3.2.8/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Ref.h:188:76: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: If you read the docu you linked to, you see that this feature is only available starting from Eigen 3.3. Your error log indicates that you are using Eigen 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

As chtz noted, the problem was the version of Eigen I was using. You need to use Eigen 3.3 or above.